# How to assign returned data to variable - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The SendOTP function works fine and returns data. I am trying to assign that to a variable.

**JS:**

```
var SentStatus = "";
DataFactory.SendOTP('39487539847')
.success(function (data, status) {
console.log('1 : ' + data);
console.log('2 : ' + JSON.parse(data));
SentStatus = JSON.parse(data);
})
.error(function (data, status) {
SentStatus = JSON.parse(data);
});
console.log('3 : ' + SentStatus);
```

In the browser console I see:

```
3 :
1 : "\"200\""
2 : 200
```

1. Why is the SentStatus empty.
2. How come the order is 3,1,2. Shouldnt
   this be 1,2,3

**EDIT:**

```
var SentStatus = "";
DataFactory.SendOTP('39487539847')
.then(function (data, status) {        
SMSSentStatus = JSON.parse(data);
})
.catch(function (data, status) {
SMSSentStatus = JSON.parse(data);
})
.finally(function () {
console.log('3 : ' + SMSSentStatus);
});

dataFactory.SendOTP = function (mobileNumber) {
return $http({
  url: GlobalVariables.vcAPIBaseUrl + "SendOTP",
  method: "GET",
  params: {
    mobileNumber: mobileNumber                
  }
  }).success(function (data, status) {            
  }).error(function (data, status) {            
  });        
};
```

**Solved:**
The .then(),catch() and .finally() worked. I was just not reading the data correctly.
It had to be `SMSSentStatus = JSON.parse(data.data)` in my case.

Comment: did you try printing SentStaus iniside (after console.log('2 : '...) statement ?

Comment: @Jan.Yes, it prints the value inside success. But the fn. could be success or failure. So I want to check the variable has any value after the fn. is done. How to proceed ?

Comment: Console stmt executes asynchronously. If try calling another function and use it there value will be assigned. (stmt 3 is executed first before any others)

Answer (score 3):

here success and error are callback functions that mean async in nature a call is sent to DataFactoru.SendOTP and event is registered with event listner and wait for the response in the mean while your console.log('3 : ' + SentStatus); run concurrently and obviously you don't have value yet so it simply prints "3:".After getting response it start success function and prints your other two consoles.

So order is

3->1->2 simple :-)

sorry for bad english